# Mallet download issues

Tags: mallet

I am really new to this type of computer work and am having trouble creating the path. I looked up a tutorial on how to do this online and followed everything to a tee, but when I try to change the directory path it is not working. Here's what I did - 
download Java Development Kit
Download Mallet 2.0.7
Move Mallet 2.0.7 download to my c-drive
added a new environmental variable - C:\mallet-2.0.7
Using the cmd I've got C:>cd mallet-2.0.7
Then I get the error message "The system cannot find the path specified"
Anyone have tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a windows issue, not a Mallet issue, but please note that Mallet 2.0.7 is out of date. 2.0.8 has many bug fixes and performance improvements.